# What is the detailed token content of "Firefly: The Game" and its expansions?

Tags: firefly

If you look in the game rulebook you'll see that it states that the game has "167 tokens". This seems quite unspecific to me. The Blue Sun- and the Pirates & Bounty Hunters-expansions are equally unspecific in what token content they have (88 and 41 respectively).

[Indie Bard](http://indiebard.com/bad-design-firefly-board-games-token-addiction/) gives a more specific content list but only for the basic game, and without any reference to any official source.

Google searches of "... token details", "... token specification" and "... token content" has turned me down so far.

My questions are the following:

- Is the Indie Bard list correct?
- If not, what is the correct content list of the tokens in the game?
- What is the token content of the expansions of the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some more research, I found this table.[1]

```
|                      | Firefly  | Pirates  | Blue sun | Kalidasa |
|----------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| Dino                 |        1 |          |          |          |
| Reaver/Alliance card |        1 |          |          |          |
| Disgruntled          |       20 |        4 |        7 |        6 |
| Parts                |       20 |        5 |          |          |
| Fuel                 |       44 |       10 |          |          |
| Warrant/Goal         |       13 |        5 |        4 |          |
| Passenger/Fugitive   |       28 |        5 |          |          |
| Cargo/Contraband     |       40 |        5 |          |          |
| Haven                |          |        7 |        7 |          |
| Alert Tokens         |          |          |       70 |       36 |
| Complete             |          |          |          |       18 |
| Higgins field        |          |          |          |        1 |
| Corvette card        |          |          |          |        1 |
```

It is not an official source but it corresponds well to those unboxing videos I've seen.[2][3][4]

The numbers for the Kalidasa expansion was counted during unboxing performed by post author.

So the answers to my original questions would be

- Yes.
- See table.
- See table.

## References

1. http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/18195471#18195471, read 2015-02-18 20:00.
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHS373VHmNk&t=0m48s, viewed 2015-02-18 20:02.
3. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9r95D01XO14&t=2m22s, viewed 2015-02-18 20:02.
4. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BNFi0W6w0s&t=1m15s, viewed 2015-02-18 20:02.